# Does VSCode accurately display the correct Typescipt type in tooltip? no-unnecessary-type-assertion Error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm trying to better understand `const assertions` in TS

Consider the array `allDeviceTypes` in the image below, when i hover over the variable name  VSCode tells me that the return type is `string[]`

[image: Typesciprt]

However if I use a const assertion to narrow the type 
I see the desired narrowed type but I'm met with the TSLint error:

`This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression. (no-unnecessary-type-assertion)tslint(1)`

So which is it? Is the type of the expression the same or is `VSCode 1.40.0`+ `TSlint 5.11.0` not displaying the right type in the tooltip?

[image]

Comment: Did you test using `tsc`? The compiler has the final say on what's correct and what's not

Answer (score 1):

VS code is correct, it talks to a typescript language server to provide the type information when you hover, so it shows the exact same type information as the typescript compiler has.

I've sometimes found TS lint to be buggy too and a quick search finds that others have also had issues with this rule.

Something else worth considering is TS lint is close to being deprecated, see this post from the maintainers: https://link.medium.com/T2BsQB3500.

You might consider switching to ES lint, or just disable the rule on that line.

Comment: so VSCode is showing the right types, but tslint (through vscode) is giving false errors you think?